# android coordinatorlayout hide appbarlayout inside fragment with bottomnavigation

Tags: android

I want to build a nice animation to hide both AppBarLayout and BottomNavigationView when the user scrolls through content. I managed to hide them both and works exactly as I want, the problem is that I want to include the AppBarLayout only in one fragment. Is there a way how to manage do this? I tried to put the AppBarLayout content inside the fragment but the animation will stop working.

To understand better what I am trying to achieve, see the gif below. The AppBarLayout Part I would like it to be inside the fragment not the activity.

[image]

Here is my current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_appbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/background">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/settings"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="3dp"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="2dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="24dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="24dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="24dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="24dp"
                app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_romania_heart"
                app:startIconTint="@null"
                android:hint="@string/cautare"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="24dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    android:inputType="text" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/settings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/search_bar"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/search_bar"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/search_bar"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/result_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragNavHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_navigation" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.PrimarySurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You don't want animation or existence of AppBarLayout? why you don't simply hide the toolbar?

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi I want animation on both AppBarLayout and BottomNavigation, the problem is that if I do nested coordinatorlayout the bottom navigation will stop working.

Comment: I still didn't understand the problem. Maybe you can add photo about what you want to achieve. I already using AppBarLayout and bottom navigation animations and handle the desired behavior with a helper class.

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi I edited the post with additional information and added a gif image.